# join column_A and column_B in Table_1A to Table_2A column_C only

Tags: mysql, sql

In Table_1A, both column_A and column_B are equal to Table_2A column_C. How do you select from the 2 tables using the inner join or any other way?

Comment: Please clarify your question - perhaps read this :  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056

Comment: Not clear, have you consulted any tutorial? Its better to first have knowledge about SQL concepts.

Comment: thank you for the advice I will study SQL first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that you want two joins:

```
select t1.*, . . .
from Table_1A t1 left join
     Table_2A t2a
     on t2a.column_C = t1.column_A left join
     Table_2A t2b
     on t2b.column_C = t1.column_B
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from Table_1A t1
Inner join Table_2A t2 
on t2.column_C = t1.column_A
or t2.column_C = t1.column_B
```

This will get you data from both tables where there is a match between `column_A` and `column_C` or `column_B` and `column_C`